# Convert scoped enum to underlying type

Tags: c++, enums, c++17

Given a scoped enum, is it possible to convert to the underlying type without explicitly specifying the underlying type?

Example:

```
enum class HeapCorruptionDetectMethod {//default is int
    write_on_freed,
    buffer_underrun,
    buffer_overrun
};

auto active_method = HeapCorruptionDetectMethod::write_on_freed;

//...

//agnostic about the underlying type:
auto index = static_cast<*underlying_type*>(active_method);
```

In other words, is it possible to query the underlying type?

Comment: I’m somewhat amused, since this is *literally* the first Google hit for “[underlying_type](https://www.google.com/search?q=underlying_type)”.

Comment: sorry for picking on words, but `auto` and getting the underlying type without explicitly mentioning it I would not call "agnostic". The type is still there, you just dont have to mention it explicitly. `index` is of certain type and depending on how you use it, its type can make a difference

Answer (score 1):

You can try following template function which I find very handy and expressive:

```cpp
template <typename Enum>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<Enum>::value, typename std::underlying_type<Enum>::type>::type
get_underlying(Enum const& value) {
    return static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<Enum>::type>(value);
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```cpp
enum class Foo : int {
    A = 0,
    B = 1
};

int main() {
    std::cout << get_underlying(Foo::A) << std::endl; // 0
    std::cout << get_underlying(Foo::B) << std::endl; // 1

    return 0;
}
```

Check it out [live](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:32,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:32,positionLineNumber:17,selectionStartColumn:32,selectionStartLineNumber:17,startColumn:32,startLineNumber:17),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+Enum%3E%0Aconstexpr+typename+std::enable_if%3Cstd::is_enum%3CEnum%3E::value,+typename+std::underlying_type%3CEnum%3E::type%3E::type%0Aget_underlying(Enum+const%26+value)+%7B%0A++++return+static_cast%3Ctypename+std::underlying_type%3CEnum%3E::type%3E(value)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aenum+class+Foo+:+int+%7B%0A++++A+%3D+0,%0A++++B+%3D+1%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+get_underlying(Foo::A)+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+get_underlying(Foo::B)+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:49.85494633014216,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Comment: what is the purpose of the function? Why not simply `static_cast<std::underlying_type<Foo>::type>(Foo::A);` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 just a handy function, more readable and generic. you don't like it?

Comment: frankly, no. I dont see the benefit of using it. Basically you just give a different name to something that already exists, this rather decreases readability. `static_cast` and `std::underlying_type` I know, with `get_underlying` I have to read the function to know what it does

Comment: @idclev463035818 hmm, i would say it increases readability (i.e. improves code expressiveness) by hiding things that are unnecessary to know

Comment: i have a clear opinion, but I didnt vote, because it is just an opinion. Readability is subjective, though consider that what you want to do is "cast to the underlying type", so neither `static_cast` nor `std::underlying_type` are unnecessary to know, rather they are the standard way to express exactly that